# Search erroneous logger definitions in Java classes using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea

Sometimes when I review java codes, I see logger definitions are copy+pasted from other classes, so logger definitions are incorrect. For example :

```
public class AClass {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BClass.class); // instead of AClass.class

}
```

Is there a way to find all similar classes using a single search in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: You could just search for LoggerFactory.getLogger and see in the search result where there is a mismatch. Why don't you use `getClass()` method instead of hardcoding class name?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The codes are already written before, so I don't want to change them with getClass(). Find in Path and typing "LoggerFactory.getLogger" is fine but then I have to handle 1000+ search results. I need a pattern like LoggerFactory.getLogger(!$CLASS_NAME$.class)